# Error updating Text

Tags: matlab

I am using MATLAB to plot the waveforms from the different earthquakes and get a correlation coefficient between the waveforms.  I am using the 2014b version. Initially when I run the code, there was no error.  However, this error started popping up now.

The warning is as follows:

```
Warning: Error updating Text. Following is the chain of causes of the error:

 String must have valid interpreter syntax:
Master event waveform: Twaveforms\15. AAC3 SN

Warning: Error updating Text. Following is the chain of causes of the error:

 String must have valid interpreter syntax:
Secondary event waveform: Twaveforms\15. AAC3 SE
```

`AAC3` is one of my 4 stations and `SE` is a phase

The command I used is:

```
titleP1=['Secondary event waveform:',' ',Secondfile(57:70),' ',Secondsta,' ',PhaseType];
```

I tried replacing `':'` after the word `'waveform'` but failed every time.
Does anyone have a good suggestion to help fix this error?

Comment: Thanks rayryeng. That was it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error is pretty clear.  The string contained in `Secondfile` contains a `\`.  Titles in plots can interpret LaTeX syntax and you prepend a `\` before the LaTeX command.  What's happening here is that it is trying to interpret the command `\15`, which is an undefined LaTeX command.

As such, you need to change `Secondfile` so that it either doesn't contain the `\` character, or if you really must, add a **second** `\` so that it can be interpreted as a `\` character when displaying the title (i.e. `\\`).

I'm assuming you want the latter option, so you can try doing something like this to add in an additional `\` character for your title.

```
%// Get string from Secondfile
s = Secondfile(57:70);

%// Use regexprep to change any characters that contain \ to \\
s = regexprep(s, '\\', '\\\\');

%// Use the changed string and make the title
titleP1=['Secondary event waveform:',' ',s,' ',Secondsta,' ',PhaseType];
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also turn the interpreter off:

I presume you used

```
title(titleP1)
```

try instead:

```
title(titleP1, 'interpreter', 'none')
```